# Update database query is not working using php

Tags: php

I have used query as follows

```
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE `payment_details` SET `txnid`='{$txnid}',`amount`='{$amount}',`email`='{$email}',`firstname`='{$firstname}',`phone`='{$phone}',`productinfo`='{$productinfo}'  
   WHERE `id`='{$id}' ") 
OR die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: $id =$_POST['id'];
 $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
 $email =$_POST['email'];
 $phone =$_POST['phone'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $service_provider =$_POST['service_provider'];
 $amount =$_POST['amount'];
 $txnid =$_POST['txnid'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $surl =$_POST['surl'];
 $furl =$_POST['furl'];

Comment: Why are you using `{}` ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: here are three link 
grpictures.in/intel/userportal/mithlesh.txt 
grpictures.in/intel/userportal/payment.txt 
grpictures.in/intel/userportal/success.txt

Comment: when i change id =1 or 2 i will work but when i used id = $id i not get  update in to database

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/mithlesh.txt

Comment: $id =$_POST['id']; actually  problen is in this line.when i used var_dump($id); is give nul value  so how can i fixed

Comment: the the above page .............

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/mithlesh.txt

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/payment.txt

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/success.txt\

Comment: You should read up on PDO and/or mysqli, since mysql has been removed in PHP 7.0. Furthermore, you should read up on prepared statements. Inserting variables directly into your query is a HUGE security risk and MUST be avoided at all times.

Comment: thank for your help

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to use the `{ }` in your variable assignment in the query. So removing those from the query, it becomes:

```
$q = mysql_query("UPDATE payment_details SET 
txnid='$txnid',
amount=$amount',
email='$email',
firstname='$firstname',
phone='$phone',
productinfo='$productinfo' 
WHERE id='$id'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: the value is not updting into database in php mysql

Comment: Please write this: `$q = "UPDATE payment_details SET 
txnid='$txnid', amount='$amount', email='$email', firstname='$firstname', phone='$phone', productinfo='$productinfo' WHERE id='$id'"; echo $q; exit();` and show me its output

Comment: UPDATE payment_details SET txnid='95075', amount='10', email='mithlesh@webrankey.com', firstname='Mithlesh', phone='96789056', productinfo='werwerw' WHERE id=''

Comment: So that means you don't have a value in `$id` field. Thats all.

Comment: yes  i i have put if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $id =$_POST['id'];
 //var_dump($usd_id); 
 
 $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
 $email =$_POST['email'];
 $phone =$_POST['phone'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $service_provider =$_POST['service_provider'];
 $amount =$_POST['amount'];
 $txnid =$_POST['txnid'];
 $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
 $surl =$_POST['surl'];
 $furl =$_POST['furl'];

Comment: See your comment above, how the query is formed. It doesn't have the `$id` value. Check that first.

Comment: when i tried $id =$_POST['id']; var_dump($id); its gives null

Comment: Check the FORM which submits to this script. That form doesn't have any field for the $id variable.

Comment: how do put the id vaue can u help me on that

Comment: here is m: 
grpictures.in/intel/userportal/mithlesh.txty from link

Comment: can you asset mn on that

Comment: I dont know about your FORM which is submitted to this script. But usually during EDIT, we pass the ID of the record being edit as a `hidden` field to the update script. E.g., `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="somevalue">` and include it inside your FORM tag in the EDIT page

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_POST['id'];  ?>"> i put this code but nothing happen

Comment: try echoing from $_GET['id']. Probably the ID will be brought to the EDIT form via a GET variable.

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/payment.txt                                                                              thsi is my link

Comment: grpictures.in/intel/userportal/payment.txt